# Getting error: d3.geoAlbersUsa is not a function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a d3 map of US states in an Angular 5 project, following below example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

So when I write the code in .ts file and compile it, it gives me an error stating : 'd3.geoAlbersUsa is not a function'.

Following is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3TimeFormat from 'd3-time-format';
import * as d3 from 'd3-selection';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
import * as d3Shape from 'd3-shape';
import * as d3Array from 'd3-array';
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as topo from 'topojson';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.callMap();
  } 

  callMap() {
    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    active = d3.select(null);

    var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("click", reset);

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

    d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
      if (error) throw error;

      g.selectAll("path")
          .data(topo.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("class", "feature")
          .on("click", clicked);

      g.append("path")
          .datum(topo.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
          .attr("class", "mesh")
          .attr("d", path);
    });
    ....
    ....
```

I am including following scripts in index.html:

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-request.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there something wrong here you need "d3-geo as d3" not "d3-selection" and the methods will be like that "d3.geo.albersUsa" not "d3.geoAlbersUsa"

Comment: Thanks for reply but when try to change import statement from 'd3-selection' to either 'd3' or 'd3-geo', it gives error: Cannot read property 'albersUsa' of undefined.

Comment: did you install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3-geo d3-geo type and I found the geoAlbersUsa function there https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-geo/d3-geo-tests.ts#L391

Answer (score 1):

It should be `d3.geo.albersUsa()` and `geoPath` should be `d3.geo.path()`